# Error: j_id0:j_id1:j_id28:j_id30: Validation Error: Value is required

Tags: visualforce, validation, error-messages

I am getting above ugly error.How to clean the error without custom error handing in controller.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EventController"> 
<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:pageBlock >
<p>
Please select 
</p>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectType}" required="true">
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!Option}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
<apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: A hack, but quick, would be to put an id="thePage" on the apex:page component, then an id="theForm" on the apex:form component, an id="thePageBlock" on the apex:pageBlock component, and finally an id="theRadio" on the apex:selectRadio component. Then the error would display as `Error: thePage:theForm:thePageBlock:theRadio: Validation Error: Value is required`. Of course you don't have to use the labels as I suggested.  Note, if your controller defaulted the value of {!selectType} in its getter method, then the radio button would always have a value and the error could be avoided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the label attributed on your selectRadio, that value would be displayed instead of the j-id0.....

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EventController"> 
<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:pageBlock >
<p>
Please select 
</p>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectType}" label="Choose One" required="true">
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!Option}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
<apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The label is key re this error...

Answer (score 2):

Each one of the `j_id#` in the chain represent an Id for an apex tag, if you assign them Ids, then it will show `YourIdName:NextIdName:AndSoON`

If I use your example and add Ids as so:

```
<apex:form id="form">
  <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
  <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock">
    <p>Please select </p>
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectType}" required="true" id="radioSelectType">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Option}"/>
    </apex:selectRadio>
    <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" id="buttonNext" />
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

The error might be `form:pageBlock:radioSelectType` and then the error message. As for changing what the error message says, this is only possible (as far as I know) with a controller.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @JimRae answer, when using pageBlockSectionItem, the label for the error message can even be different than the value for the "label" portion of the pageBlockSectionItem label-value pair

Example:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:outputText value="Please choose an option"/>
  <apex:selectRadio value={!selectType}" required="true" label="option">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Option}"/>
  </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The form will display:

```
Please choose an option <the radio buttons>
```

but if no radio option chosen when commandButton clicked, the error message will simply say:

```
Option : Validation Error : Value is required
```

omitting the "please etc" pleasantries